# how to set property for parent class inside child class in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two class one is Vehicle and one is BMW, I know I can create a color as property unver Vehicle. However how I set the property inside class BMW 
but i am still able to access color as `bmw.info,color`? Can I do something like following?

```py
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name
        self._color = None

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, color):
        self._color = color
class BMW:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.info = Vehicle(name)
#can I do something like
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name

class BMW:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.info = Vehicle(name)

    setattr(self.info, "color", None)

    @info.property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @info.color.setter
    def color(self, color):
        self._color = color

bmw = BMW('sister')
print(bmw.info.color)
bmw.info.color = 'red'
print(bmw.info.color)
```

Comment: You aren't doing any inheritence... which is designed for things like this.

Comment: even I do inheritence, how can i create a Vehicle's property from BMW?

Comment: I want to add a property after the instance is created. the case I have is I have to use Vehicle class as general case and different class carry info as attribution with different property